AM radio over rainforest
Where can I find information about the AM radio reception at tropical rainforest environment?
Here in Colombia exists one of the most humid environments on the planet.
I can't find information about AM radio quality at such a place.
But in general terms, how does the humidity of the dense rainforest affect AM radio reception in such an environment?

Hi Ando and welcome. FYI: I've edited the question a bit, so that it is focused more about the general physics concept and a bit less about what happens at a specific locale.

Probably more suited to [ham.se]
